# PHP Internal Server Error, Long Big Script on shared Godaddy Hosting

Tags: php, json

I have a **json** file for more than 100000+ members, I am trying to import them to database, I coded the script and script runs fine and data do gets to insert, but not all of the data, after some time I get internal server error and only 100 or so members get inserted from json file.

I already have tried to set the max execution time to unlimited but still no output.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',true);
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

it only gives server time out after some time. if it would be possible to run script even for 1 hour will be great.

i cant run script on local wamp, my internet speed is very slow and script also downloads and resized profile images of members too. plus if my internet is disconnected that would also interrupt the script.

Is there any way i can by pass time out.

I heard about doing it in cron job but not sure if cron job has the same time limit.

the json file i am trying to import was of 122mb, but i divied it in to 34 parts which took some time..

the file now i am trying to run is of 4mb in size, but still after minute or two i get internal server error.

Comment: The local command line and cron jobs (on the server) don't have time limits. For one time scripts like imports this is the best way to run them.

Comment: "it only gives server time out after some time. "

This means what request goes though web server (nginx, apache, etc).
But you need to run the script through cli(ssh):

`php /path/to/script.php`